# Pycharm pyautogui problem, cant start two line program

Tags: python, pycharm

Just wanted to import PyAutoGUI, but got this error.

What am I supposed to do?

[image: code image]

Comment: Your error message indicates a line in `tkinter/__init__.py` that reads `(Image  in 8.0);`.  But the actual file shouldn't contain any such line; the closest I see reads `# (Image commands are new in 8.0)`.  So it would appear that at least one file in your Python installation has become badly mangled.  Unless you have some idea as to how this particular file got mangled, I'd suggest a reinstallation of Python as there's no telling what else has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you have a  syntax error at the end of the line of code. 
You don’t need the final semi colon in the **init**.py script.
Python does not need them.

Comment: ty for a replay, but what colon do u mean?

Comment: Don’t worry, i mean that you should not put the ; at the end of the line